# Unique indexes in YugabyteDB YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Question about `UNIQUE` keyword. I can create an index with unique keyword inside, like:

```
CREATE unique INDEX warehouse_idx ON orders (warehouse_id);
```

But I do not see this opportunity in the documentation. This is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example on creating the index on the docs page: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/api/ycql/ddl_create_index/#create-a-table-with-a-unique-index